# Redirect outgoing https to another https

Tags: http, xampp, localhost, redirect

Let's say I have two domains, both are located external

```
https://domain1.com

https://domain2.com
```

I would like to learn how to redirect the outgoing connection to `https://domain1.com` to `https://domain2.com` from my pc.

Actually what I want to do is.

When I enter the url `https://domain1.com/test/test.php`

I would like to redirect it to `https://domain2.com/test/test.php`

I just want to do it on my local windows pc. I tried to play with hosts file but it didn't work.

Any linux solutions are also welcome, I can switch to linux for it.

Answer (score -1):

Just add 'header("Location:https://domain2.com/test/test.php");' line without single quotes in the 'test.php' file in the 'domain1.com'.Now simply try to load the page(https://domain1.com/test/test.php) it will be redirected to 'https://domain2.com/test/test.php'.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any control on https://domain1.com

I need to make the redirection on my computer.

Comment: okk then you can go to 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc' and find a file  named as 'host' open and just enter one more line in last 'https://domain1.com/test/test/php    https://domain2.com/test/test.php' (without '#' as Hashtag is used to make comment).

Comment: first link is what you want to redirect and second is where you want to